# How to get MeetingRegistration for online meeting using MS365 Graph beta API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

In order to allow registration for a MS Teams Webinar directly on my own website, I am trying to use the MS 365 Graph API to register webinar participants.

When [trying to get the MeetingRegistration for an Online-Webinar scheduled using MS Teams](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=me%2FonlineMeetings%2FMSo0YTZlYzYxYy05YTJhLTQ0M2QtYjhhNi0xZTJiZWFkODA3NjkqMCoqMTk6bWVldGluZ19NV1E0WW1aa056VXRZakptWWkwME1HSmxMV0V6WTJRdE56WTFOMkZqWW1ZMVlXVXpAdGhyZWFkLnYy%2Fregistration%3F%24expand%3Dmicrosoft.graph.meetingRegistration%2FcustomQuestions&method=GET&version=beta&GraphUrl=https://graph.microsoft.com), the Graph API (beta) endpoint returns the following error message:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/onlineMeetings/{meeting id}/registration?$expand=microsoft.graph.meetingRegistration/customQuestions
```

Response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidArgument",
        "message": "Object of type '<>f__AnonymousType0`1[<>f__AnonymousType1`2[System.String,System.String]]' cannot be converted to type 'Microsoft.Graph.Registration.MeetingRegistrationBase'.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "d05718a2-f13b-42a3-a21f-0ef689bd1c3a",
            "date": "2023-07-11T17:59:37",
            "client-request-id": "8a884674-07e0-089d-84d9-d5f83e903171"
        }
    }
}
```

Retrieving the OnlineMeeting itself from the v1.0 version of the API works without issues using the exact same meeting ID:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onlineMeetings/{meeting id}
```

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('4a6ec61c-9a2a-443d-b8a6-1e2bead80769')/onlineMeetings/$entity",
    "id": "MSo0YTZlYzYxYy05YTJhLTQ0M2QtYjhhNi0xZTJiZWFkODA3NjkqMCoqMTk6bWVldGluZ19NV1E0WW1aa056VXRZakptWWkwME1HSmxMV0V6WTJRdE56WTFOMkZqWW1ZMVlXVXpAdGhyZWFkLnYy",
    "creationDateTime": "2023-06-17T19:13:56.3131303Z",
    "startDateTime": "2023-07-27T20:00:00Z",
    "endDateTime": "2023-07-27T21:00:00Z",
    "joinUrl": "https://teams.microsoft.com/l/meetup-join/19%3ameetin...
(truncated)
```

After doing some research online, I found that the meeting ID as actually a simple base 64 encoded data structure as described [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/11696).

Other people had issues when the meeting id was incomplete, e.g., missing the organizer id. But this is not the case here.